# How to resolve space from jsp to servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

While passing string with space (ex: `Item 1`) from jsp to servlet, the result in servlet from request is only string before the space (ex: `Item`). How to resolve this?

JSP:
(Fetching the values from `.txt` file and populate the values in jsp)
s1[i] is: `Item 1`

```
<input type="hidden" name="ItemsFromJsp" value=<%=sItems%>> <%=s1[i]%>
```

Servelt:

```
String[] sItemsFromJsp = request.getParameterValues("ItemsFromJsp");
```

OutPut:

```
sItemsFromJsp---------- Item
```

Output Should be: `Item 1`

Note: If Sending Like Item1 as input, the O/P is Item1

Comment: I thought that container or the browser will replace space for you automatically by html entities. Maybe you have to do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes:   :)

```
value="<%=sItems%>">
```

P.S.
You are aware of `getParameter` in the case of one single parameter?

```
String sItemsFromJsp = request.getParameter("ItemsFromJsp");
```

or

```
String[] sItemsFromJsp = request.getParameter("ItemsFromJsp").split(",\\s+");
```

if you have a comma separated item list.

Comment: Hi Joop Eggen,Thanks for ur reply. yes its working with Quotes. Thanks lot.